# Quiet supply drops

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

From time to time, Quiet will call a supply drop for you. It seems to be identical to the one called from your iDroid.

What are the requirements for Quiet to call a supply drop for you?

**Reference**: Official guide book, page 302: *Retrieve a supply drop ordered by Quiet (up to five times per mission/free-roaming sequence) +0.5 bound*. On page 305 (same book), you get a table called *Quiet's Supply Drops* which tells you what she gives you depending on your bound -- there are four tiers. However, there are no indications as to why or when she does order a drop. You have to keep your eyes open.  I am assuming it is when one of your items runs out.

Comment: I have not had this happen in the entire game and I use Quiet on every deployment... I also never run low on ammo and conserve carefully, so maybe it has to do with that?

Comment: @DangerZone: Possibly. ^_~ I tend to go on fishing expeditions where I tranq and Fulton extract everything in sight. After three/four days in game, I am running low on everything.  And have flies buzzing around Big Boss... Time for a shower.

Comment: I've never seen this happen. How do you know it's Quiet doing it? Do you get some kind of "Quiet called supply drop" message? Can you post screenshots? The only time I've gotten a supply drop I didn't call myself was in the Sahelanthropus fight, where the Diamond Dogs are actively dropping supplies and calling airstrikes and firing artillery to support you.

Comment: @user2357112: See my edit.

Comment: Come to think of it, I've seen mysterious piles of supplies lying on the ground a few times, always while using Quiet as a buddy. I've never noticed her call a supply drop, though, and I've never spotted those supplies coming down from the sky. I assumed those supplies were just normally there, but maybe Quiet left them for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my experience, when Quiet scouts an outpost, she will gather supplies whilst moving through the area, and then leave said supplies at or near one of her vantage points.

These supplies are not being dropped in from the sky.

Comment: Plausible, but how do you know this is what happened? Did you see her leave them? Were the supplies missing from a storehouse?

Comment: This is all from memory, and I can't verify due to spoilery reasons, but it's simple cause and effect. 1) No supplies are lying around. 2) Quiet is ordered to scout an outpost, and does so. 3) There are now supplies lying around. Can anyone else please check this and comment? Note: as @DangerZone mentioned, it may also be related to current supply levels, so burn some ammo/suppressors/etc before setting her off.

Comment: This agrees with my experience of the matter, so I am accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Quiet does drop 3 supply packages with all ammo and items you have deployed with. From experience and research, these drops are always on her attack spots after she was scouting an outpost.

She doesn't drop them every time, and most times when she drops them I've found I don't really need it.